# How to use a JSON data source with assemble.io?

Tags: json, assemble

The assemble.io [documentation](http://assemble.io/docs/Data.html) gives some examples of using simple JSON as a data source, such as:

```
{
  "title": "Assemble" ,
  "author": "Brian Woodward" 
 }
```

But, what if I wanted to use a more complex JSON structure for my data (to display a list of books on a single page)? How can that be done?

```
{
    "books": [
        {
            "title": "Book A",
            "author": "Fred"
        },
        {
            "title": "Book 47",
            "author": "Joe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say your `library.json` contain:

```
{
    "books": [
        {
            "title": "Book A",
            "author": "Fred"
        },
        {
            "title": "Book 47",
            "author": "Joe"
        }
    ]
}
```

Use {{each}} (Assemble use handlebarjs for default templating) to display a list of books on a single page:

```
{{#each library.books}}
  {{title}} - {{author}}
{{/each}}
```